# Packaging a file into a jar at a specific directory

Tags: java, ant, jar

Pardon me for asking a simple qustion. I am new to ant and I am trying to build a jar file. I have a file

> jaxb.index

inside the package structure

> com/mycom/mg/adapter

I am trying to package this file into my jar using

```
<target name="dist" description="Create distributable jar file">
   <jar destfile="${common.lib.dir}/${dist.file}">
      <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
      <zipfileset  
            file="${sms.syn.dir}/jaxb.index">
      </zipfileset>
  </jar>
</target>
```

I want the jaxb.index file in the same package com/mycom/mg/adapter, but when i use the code above, ant is adding it to the root of the jar. Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT**
Using

```
<zipfileset  
            file="${sms.syn.dir}/jaxb.index" fullpath="com/mycom/mg/adapter">
</zipfileset>
```

doesnt help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you should use attribute `prefix` instead of `fullpath`:

```
<zipfileset  
            file="${sms.syn.dir}/jaxb.index" prefix="com/mycom/mg/adapter">
</zipfileset>
```

I think that `fullpath` should work also but you should specify really full path, i.e. path with the file name: `fullpath="com/mycom/mg/adapter/jaxb.index"`

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use like this

```
<zipfileset dir="${sms.syn.dir}" includes="jaxb.index" fullpath="com/mycom/mg/adapter"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just had to add the file name jaxb.index to fullpath attribute as AlexR suggested